# Get Campaign Type with reports? API Adwords

Tags: google-ads-api

How do i get the right Campaing Type?

In Adwords the Campaing Types are:

```
Search Network with Display Select
Search Network only
Display Network only
Shopping
Video
```

But when i call through the API, the only available results are for AdvertisingChannelType;

```
 UNKNOWN    
 SEARCH 
 DISPLAY    
 SHOPPING   
 VIDEO  
 MULTI_CHANNEL
```

Let's say "Search Network with Display Select" is Multi-Channel, but im trying the api and i'm getting :

```
"advertisingChannel": "Search"
```

on a Campaign that is :

```
Search Network with Display Select
```

Im using:

```
$reportDefinition->reportType = 'CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT';
```

Answer (score 2):

**From the AdWords API Group:**

You can only detect this by using `CampaignService` and checking for Campaign objects where:

`advertisingChannelType` is `SEARCH`
`NetworkSetting.targetContentNetwork` is `false` (for Search only campaigns) or `true` (for Search network with display select campaigns)

Some other options/tips are:

You could include the `AdNetworkType1` field in the report to detect if a campaign has impressions on the Display network.
You could add labels to your search only or search with display select campaigns, then use those labels in your reporting filters.